# Complex Fourier series for $f(x)=e^{-iax}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

Condition: $a$ is a real number but not integer.

(1) $f(x)=e^{-iax},(-\pi<x<= \pi)$. expand $f(x)$ onto the real axis with period $T=2\pi$. Find the complex Fourier series of $f(x)$.

(2) prove that $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+a)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{(sin(a\pi))^2}$$

My solution for question 1 is as below. Is it right? How can I do the 2nd question?

Solution for 1: $c_n= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-iax}e^{-inx} dx = \frac{sin((a+n)\pi)}{i\pi(a+n)}$

so $ f(x)= \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{sin((a+n)\pi)}{i\pi(a+n)}* e^{inx} $

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to MSE. We generally condemn uploading pictures as a part of posting a problem, since you know how to write in LaTeX, why not try using it? Also please write whatever you have tried to solve the 2nd problem. A complete guide for using LaTeX is found here: https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols

Comment: Apply Parseval identity

Comment: @ Anik Bhowmick, Sorry, I already delete the picture and use the LaTex for my solution trial.

Comment: @ Ryszard Szwarc, Yeah, I checked this theorem and know solved the 2nd question, thanks for your help.